# An error occurred (401) when calling the PutBackupVaultNotifications operation:

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sns, aws-backup

Hi i am getting an error while creating backupvault notification this is my script

```
aws backup put-backup-vault-notifications --endpoint-url https://ap-south-1.console.aws.amazon.com/backup --backup-vault-name testing --sns-topic-arn arn:aws:sns:ap-south-1:908704518654:My_Alert --backup-vault-events BACKUP_JOB_COMPLETED
```

Comment: Hi, I ran the backup command without any issues. Can you post the 401 error, you facing?

Comment: Greeting error 401 when calling the putbackupvaultnotification operation: